# Where should I write a user specific log file to (and be XDG base directory compatible)

Tags: python, logging, pip

By default, pip logs errors into "~/.pip/pip.log".  Pip has an option to change the log path, and I'd like to put the log file somewhere besides ~/.pip so as not to clutter up my home directory.  Where should I put it and be [XDG base dir compatible](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)?

Right now I'm considering one of these:

- $XDG_DATA_HOME (typically $HOME/.local/share)
- $XDG_CACHE_HOME (typically $HOME/.cache)

Comment: Well, considering that a log is neither of those...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is, for the moment, unclear.

Different software seem to handle this in different ways ([imsettings](https://code.google.com/p/imsettings/issues/detail?id=30) puts it in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`, 
[profanity](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/profanitydev/YQLDobYEfnA/kpodU-qckOIJ) in `$XDG_DATA_HOME`).

[Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/XDGBaseDirectorySpecification), however, has a proposal which I can get behind (emphasis mine):

> This is a recurring request/complaint (see [this](http://lists.freedesktop.org/pipermail/xdg/2009-February/010191.html) or [this](http://lists.freedesktop.org/pipermail/xdg/2012-December/012598.html)) on the xdg-freedesktop mailing list to introduce another directory for state information that does not belong in any of the existing categories (see also home-dir.proposal. Examples for this information are:
>
> - history files of shells, repls, anything that uses libreadline
> - **logfiles**
> - state of application windows on exit
> - recently opened files
> - last time application was run
> - emacs: bookmarks, ido last directories, backups, auto-save files, auto-save-list
>
> The above example information is not essential data. However it should still persist on reboots of the system unlike cache data that a user might consider putting in a TMPFS. On the other hand the data is rather volatile and does not make sense to be checked into a VCS. The files are also not the data files that an application works on.
>
> A default folder for a future STATE category might be: **$HOME/.local/state**

This would effectively introduce *another* environment variable since `$XDG_DATA_HOME` usually points to `$HOME/.local/share` and this hypothetical environment variable (`$XDG_STATE_HOME`?) would point to `$HOME/.local/state`

If you really want to adhere to the current standard I would place my log files in `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` since log files aren't required to run the program.

Comment: `$XDG_STATE_HOME` is present starting with version 0.8 : https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/0.8/ar01s03.html